# Using a class out of class library as a Entity for EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization

Assume there's a `class AClass` in one of my class libraries, which I am using in multiple projects.

Nowadays I build a new project which uses this `AClass` and wants to store it into a database using Entity Framework.

I don't wanna code a wrapper class and assign each attribute from `AClass` to `AClassEntityWrapper` and vice versa.
Maybe it can be automaticly? Serialization? Idk..

On the other side I can't declare `AClass` as an Entity, cause I don't want to include the Entity Framework to all other projects too.

Is there a simple possibility to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understood your question right.
But you can map your class OnModelCreating
In your DbContext override OnModelCreating method and the configuration for AClass

```
 public class className : DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<AClass> AClasses { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AClassConfiguration());
     }
 }
```

Lets pretend your AClass has two fields

```
public class AClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class AClassConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AClass>
{
    public AClassConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("table_name");
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("name");
    }
}
```